# Symfony 2.4 how to hide/change the default base path urls for the entire project?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony

I have a website where i have done the admin panel only in Symfony, I want to hide the default path coming as /admin/web/ to /admin/.

I can't change the virtual directory path from the apache httpd.conf as they said in the Symfony documentation, because it will affect the front end of the website which is not in the Symfony framework. Also I can't move the Symfony base folder to one up above, because of the other folders that are not Symfony.

Any ideas on how to do this in .htaccess?

I want the following:

```
admin/web/viewDashboard  -> admin/viewDashboard
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simple create admin/viewDashBoard folder  and in this folder place .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (.*)(.*)/?$ ../web/viewDashboard/app.php
```

This will redirect whole traffix from admin/viewDashboard to admin/web/viewDashboard

Comment: not applicable in my case becasue there will be many urls generated dynamically via the symfony framework, i think i need something like rewrite base ...etc

Comment: This will redirect the whole traffic from this directory to app.php file so it will work for admin/viewDashboard but also for admin/viewDashboard/mymodule , admin/viewDashboard/secondmodule/ and so on

Comment: does this reditect /web/viewSeeker/app.php ? i dont think so, there are many routes like this in the framework..

Comment: But why should it be redirected? How /web/viewSeeker/app.php is connected to the question ? As I understood at the beginning you want to rewrite admin directory not all urls. Otherwise you need to clarify in question what exactly you need